# Advice on Component react-ratings-declaritive

Tags: reactjs

I am using a component which I have downloaded from below:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ratings-declarative

It works great, but I really need the functionality to disable the component in instances where I just want to display the rating, but not have the interactive element.

I have looked through the documentation and can't find anything to disable it directly. I can see some stuff on disabling inline styles, but not sure how this would work.

I have copied the raw HTML and tried to reconstruct a component with this functionality, but there seems to be so many styles to copy, I don't think this approach would work.

Can anyone advise if this is possible or recommend an alternative component which does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't call the method that sets state. I used the example and got rid of the `changeRating` method and deleted the `changeRating` attribute. If there is no way to change the state, users can't update the ratings.

```
//IMPORT STATEMENTS ETC...
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { rating: 5 }
  }
  /* YOU DON'T NEED THIS METHOD EITHER IF YOU'RE NOT CHANGING STATE
  changeRating(rating) {
    this.setState({
     rating: rating
    })
  }
  */
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Ratings 
          /*changeRating={this.changeRating} <-- GET RID OF THIS LINE*/
          rating={this.state.rating}
          widgetRatedColors='blue'>
          <Ratings.Widget />
          <Ratings.Widget />
          <Ratings.Widget
            widgetDimension='60px'
            svgIconViewBox='0 0 5 5'
            svgIconPath='M2 1 h1 v1 h1 v1 h-1 v1 h-1 v-1 h-1 v-1 h1 z'
          />
          <Ratings.Widget widgetHoverColor='black' />
          <Ratings.Widget />
        </Ratings>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <main>
        <Foo />
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('example'))
```